# Passing key and value of a map in angularjs to a dropdown in HTML

Tags: html, angularjs

I have a map in angularJs which contain keys and values. I want to pass those keys and values to my dropdown in the HTML page. I am a newbie to angularjs.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<div ng-repeat="(key, value) in map">{{key}}: {{value}}</div>

//in your case

<select>
  <option value="val" ng-repeat="(key, val) in map" >{{ key }}</option>
</select>
```

Comment: <div ng-repeat="(key, value) in map">{{key}}: {{value}}</div> why you have used a div instead of a <select> ?

Comment: It was just a use case for how to loop through map for any html tag.
 Below it I have mentioned how you can integrate it in the select dropdown.

Comment: @Madhavee you may accept the answer if it helped: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work cheers

Comment: The given solution didn't work for me. I converted my map into an array.Then only it worked.